# MS Access: .Close required after .RecordSetClone?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In an MS-Access form, I have the following code attached to an event:

```
Dim frm As Form, rs As Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

'do some stuff with rs
'
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set frm = Nothing
```

My question is: is the rs.Close required ? Is it even good (undesired side effects ?)

Comment: You should define your recordset variable as `rs As DAO.Recordset`. That is, if you're going to declare it at all. There's almost never a case where that's necessary when working with the RecordsetClone. Instead, use a WITH/END WITH block, i.e., `With Me.RecordsetClone`.

Comment: @David: the With is a good idea. I never specify the DAO part because I never reference ADO, but you're probably right and one day I'll pay for that :-/

Comment: By specifying it, you're making the compile process require less resolution of implicit objects within the namespace. While I've never seen VBA get it wrong with only a DAO reference, I'd rather tell VBA what to look at so it doesn't have to "worry" about it. It's also just better coding -- keep in mind that one of the purposes of code is to inform a programmer what's going on (not just the compiler), and specifying DAO in all cases makes it clear in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the close is not required, and the simple rule is if your code did not open the reocrdset, then you don't want to close it. So, you only want/need to close things that you opended.

So, you are using a existing built in recordset, and you did not open that recordset. Setting both to nothing as you have is not required, but it can remain in place, and does show clear your intentions you done with the objects.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think the world would end but it is always good practice to close what you open.

Access used to have a problem where if you did not dispose of some object it would not quit but instead it would minimise to the task bar and you would have to kill the task. However as you are setting the object to nothing this would not affect you

Comment: My concern in the question is that we're talking here about a *clone*, which I understand as a pointer to another pre-existing object.

Comment: But he didn't open it -- the form's RecordsetClone already exists.